# Separate comma delimited cells (varying entries) to new rows

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have .txt file (tab separated) with two columns. First column has comma separated multiple values. Input format

```
a,b,c x
a     y
c,d,e z
```

Desired output is

```
a x
b x
c x
a y
c z
d z
e z
```

The number of comma separated entries vary between 1-40. I tried following awk command, but it only works if there are two comma separated entries in first column:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[       ,]"} {print $1, $NF; print $2, $NF}' input
```

How can I modify the above command (or anything new) that can do the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F',| +' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i,$NF}'
```

set the field delimiter to space(s) or comma, print pair of all fields (up to the last field) with last field.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lane 'print "$F[0] $_ $F[2]" for glob "{$F[1]}"' file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from the input and adds them to prints
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array
- [glob](http://p3rl.org/glob) expands comma separated lists in curly brackets similarly to the shell

*Update:* You changed the specification (without marking any update). The solution remains similar, just use

```
perl -lane 'print "$_ $F[1]" for glob "{$F[0]}"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

awk's [split](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to the rescue:

```
awk '{split($1,arr,","); for (key in arr) { print arr[key],$2 }}' input
```

Comment: very nice solution! Thanks

Comment: You should mention that that will print the rows in random order courtesy of the `in` operator.

Comment: This does not produce the desired output as show in the OP.

Comment: @user3439894 - did you try to run it?
for the input specified - it produces the exact output desired.

Comment: Yes, I ran it against the info in the OP, otherwise I wouldn't have said something. The output was `b x\nc x\na x\na y\nd z\ne z\nc z` not `a x\nb x\nc x\na y\nc z\nd z\ne z` as show in the OP. Even Ed Morton commented on your answer, "You should mention that that will print the rows in random order courtesy of the in operator." I tried the answer from karakfa and it worked as output shown in the OP.

Comment: Obviously enough I also ran it against both OP input, and various other inputs.
About the "in" order, I quote the manual of awk:
"_The order in which elements of the array are accessed by this statement is determined by the internal arrangement of the array elements within awk and in standard awk cannot be controlled or changed. This can lead to problems if new elements are added to array by statements in the loop body; it is not predictable whether the for loop will reach them._"
we don't change the elements once created by split.
on kernel 4.10, the in follows the order of split.

Comment: It really doesn't matter what the manual says because your command doesn't guarantee the (logical) order shown in the OP!

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t"
}

NF == 2 {
    n = split($1, a, ",")
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        print a[i], $2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\s+(\S+)$/ \1/;s/,(.*( \S+))$/\2\n\1/;P;D' file
```

Remove extra spaces from the current line. Replace each `,` by a space followed by the last field of the current line followed by a newline. Print the first line in the current line, delete the first line and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed too

```
sed -E ':A;s/([^,]*),(.*)(\t.*$)/\1\3\n\2\3/;tA' infile
```

You get an output tab separated.

If you don't want this tab :

```
sed -E ':A;s/([^,]*),(.*)(\t.*$)/\1\3\n\2\3/;tA;s/\t/ /g' infile
```